# Haskell source generated by happy has error "parse error on input 'data'"

Tags: haskell, parser-generator, alex

I'm trying out the happy parser generator of Haskell. After generating the module in happy.hs (no problem while generating!), I run the command `ghc happy.hs`, and I get the error: `Line 297: parse error on input 'data'`. Does anyone have solutions? Or tell me where can I get the solution?

I tried loading the module in GHCi, rather than compiling it using ghc. But it seems not to be working too - I get the same error.

Code in happy.y (happy source):

```hs
-- TODO: add more of my things!!!

{
    module Main where
}
%name calc
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }
-- tokens
%token
    let { TokenLet }
    in { TokenIn }
    int { TokenInt $$ }
    var { TokenVar $$ }
    '=' { TokenEq }
    '+' { TokenPlus }
    '-' { TokenSub }
    '*' { TokenMul }
    '/' { TokenDvd }
    '(' { TokenOB }
    ')' { TokenCB }
%%
Exp : let var '=' Exp in Exp { Let $2 $4 $6 }
    | Exp1 { Exp1 $1 }
Exp1 : Exp1 '+' Term { Plus $1 $3 }
    | Exp1 '-' Term { Minus $1 $3 }
    | Term { Term $1 }
Term : Term '*' Factor { Times $1 $3 }
    | Term '/' Factor { Div $1 $3 }
    | Factor { Factor $1 }
Factor : int { Int $1 }
    | var { Var $1 }
    | '(' Exp ')' { Brack $2 }

{
    parseError :: [Token] -> a
    parseError _ = error "Parse error! please try again..."

    data Exp = Let String Exp Exp
        | Exp1 Exp1
    deriving Show

    data Exp1 = Plus Exp1 Term
        | Minus Exp1 Term
        | Term Term
    deriving Show

    data Term = Times Term Factor
        | Div Term Factor
        | Factor Factor
    deriving Show

    data Factor = Int Int
        | Var String
        | Brack Exp
    deriving Show

    -- the tokens 
    data Token = TokenLet
        | TokenIn
        | TokenInt Int
        | TokenVar String
        | TokenEq
        | TokenPlus
        | TokenMinus
        | TokenTimes
        | TokenDiv
        | TokenOB
        | TokenCB
        deriving Show

    -- the lexer
    lexer :: String -> [Token]
    lexer [] = []
    lexer (c:cs)
        | isSpace c = lexer cs
        | isAlpha c = lexVar (c:cs)
        | isDigit c = lexNum (c:cs)
    lexer ('=':cs) = TokenEq : lexer cs
    lexer ('+':cs) = TokenPlus : lexer cs
    lexer ('-':cs) = TokenMinus : lexer cs
    lexer ('*':cs) = TokenTimes : lexer cs
    lexer ('/':cs) = TokenDiv : lexer cs
    lexer ('(':cs) = TokenOB : lexer cs
    lexer (')':cs) = TokenCB : lexer cs
    lexNum cs = TokenInt (read num) : lexer rest
    where (num,rest) = span isDigit cs
    lexVar cs =
        case span isAlpha cs of
        ("let",rest) -> TokenLet : lexer rest
        ("in",rest) -> TokenIn : lexer rest
        (var,rest) -> TokenVar var : lexer rest

    -- the main function
    main = getContents >>= print . calc . lexer
}
```

Line that makes error in happy.hs and ±10 Lines(Lines 287~307, including):

```hs
287: calc tks = happyRunIdentity happySomeParser where
288:  happySomeParser = happyThen (happyParse action_0 tks) (\x -> case x of 289: {HappyAbsSyn4 z -> happyReturn z; _other -> notHappyAtAll })
290: 
291: happySeq = happyDontSeq
292:
293:
294: parseError :: [Token] -> a
295:    parseError _ = error "Parse error! please try again..."
296:
297:    data Exp = Let String Exp Exp       -- <= I get error on this line!
298:       | Exp1 Exp1
299:    deriving Show
300:
301:    data Exp1 = Plus Exp1 Term
302:        | Minus Exp1 Term
303:        | Term Term
304:    deriving Show
305:
306:    data Term = Times Term Factor
307:        | Div Term Factor
```

I expect the program to run smoothly without any errors, but it doesn't.

Comment: sorry of my English. Please, print keyword "data" in first position of string.

Comment: Anything between the brackets at the end of a happy .y file should be valid Haskell code. What you have there is not- the indentation is all off, and Haskell is a white-space sensitive language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy produces its generated code on column 1 of the file. Therefore, to have your code be considered part of the same `module`-`where` block as the generated code (which you cannot control), it must also live on column 1 of the file.

Delete four spaces from the beginning of the plain-Haskell lines of code in your happy file and you'll be on your way to the next error. Make sure that your `deriving` clauses and `where` clauses are indented one level from their surroundings when you are deleting spaces.

Comment: @Samuel Barr
Thank you all! This was very helpful! I found several other problems too and fixed them! Thanks again!